# How to scale Bitmap put, and loaded from cache initially?

Tags: android, bitmap

This is a method i created to put Bitmap into cache..

```
        //Caching method to cache images loaded from the URL's.
    public void putBitmapInDiskCache(URI imageUri, Bitmap avatar) {   
            File cacheDir = new File(MainMenu.this.getCacheDir(), "thumbnails");
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
            File cacheFile = new File(cacheDir, ""+imageUri.hashCode());   
            try {      
            cacheFile.createNewFile();       
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(cacheFile);    
            avatar.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);   


            fos.flush();       
            fos.close();    
            } catch (Exception e) {       
            Log.e("error", "Error when saving image to cache. ", e);    

            }   



            }
```

The only problem is i set the Bitmap width and height parameter initially when it is downloaded. But when it is put into cache and pulled out, it loses its width and height and becomes to big. When it is scrolled off the screen it is set correctly again. intially it loses its width and height.

EDIT: I load the bitmap with my getimagefromCache() method.

```
public void getImagesfromCache() throws MalformedURLException{
if(new File(new File(this.getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(), "thumbnails"),"" + imageCacheUri.hashCode()).exists()){
String cacheFile = this.getApplicationContext().getCacheDir() +"/thumbnails/"+ imageCacheUri.hashCode();
            ImageView i = new ImageView(this.getApplicationContext());
            FileInputStream fis = null;
            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(cacheFile);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);

             i.setImageBitmap(bm);
             i.setTag(mImageURLs);
             putBitmapInDiskCache(imageCacheUri, bm);



        //Set the BaseAdapter to a gallery, holding the images  
             ((Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery))
              .setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(MainMenu.this));
```

Comment: how do you load the bitmap image. look at the code will be better

Comment: why do you call putBitmapInDiskCache in get?

Comment: You think that may be the problem?

Comment: The call to put in get is redundunt. Otherwise these methods look fine, the problem is somewhere else. Could you add the layout xml or class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an `Matrix` parameter on the `createBitmap` method that will allow you to resize your Bitmap and so you can store it with the resolution you want. See how [here](http://www.anddev.org/resize_and_rotate_image_-_example-t621.html) (it's an excellent tutorial, by the way).

Comment: Have you noticed the link that I put in my post? There you may find the code relevant to what I was saying. The thing is that you could use it to properly scale your Bitmap and so it would be at your desired resolution. It's worth a try. The link (again) is: http://www.anddev.org/resize_and_rotate_image_-_example-t621.html